# How can i authenticate using token instead of api key for azure searchClient?

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am trying to use the searchClient library:

```
service_endpoint = os.environ["AZURE_SEARCH_SERVICE_ENDPOINT"] 
index_name = os.environ["AZURE_SEARCH_INDEX_NAME"]
key = os.environ["AZURE_SEARCH_API_KEY"]
search_client = SearchClient(service_endpoint, index_name, AzureKeyCredential(key))
```

Is there a way to create the searchclient by passing a token instead of an API or another way to authenticate without this api key?

Comment: You mean Azure AD Token? Sure, you can do that.

Comment: yes how can i add that in?

Comment: Please read this for setup: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-security-rbac?tabs=config-svc-portal%2Croles-portal%2Ctest-portal%2Ccustom-role-portal%2Cdisable-keys-portal and then using `DefaultAzureCredential` instead of `AzureKeyCredential`.

Answer (score 1):

As @Gaurav Mantri mentioned, you need to use `DefaultAzureCredential` to authorize through a token.

Here is the corrected code:

```py
from azure.search.documents import SearchClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
endpoint = "https://<resource_name>.search.windows.net"
index_name = "hotels-2"
client = SearchClient(endpoint=endpoint, index_name=index_name, credential=credential)
```

`DefaultAzureCredential` authenticates through various mechanisms. Learn more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-python#defaultazurecredential).

Output:

[image]

Ensure you provide all required roles for accessing the AI search service.

Comment: i don't need to pass credential.get_token()?

Comment: No need to pass.